# Причина ошибки. ООП

Tags: php, ооп

Есть учебный код, есть ошибка. **Прошу** объяснить что не так.

```
<?php

class ShopProduct{
  public $title = "prod";
  private $price = 0;

  function __construct($title, $price){
    $this->$title = $title;
    $this->$price = $price;
  }

  public function getPrice(){
    return $this->$price;
  }
}

class Saller{
  function sale(ShopProduct $product, $sale){
    return $product->getPrice() + $sale;
  }
}

$product = new ShopProduct("dd", 50);
$saller  = new Saller();

echo $saller->sale($product, 0.1);
echo "<br />".$saller->sale($product, 0);
```

> Ошибки
>   Notice: Undefined variable: price in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\index.php on line 13
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\index.php on line 13

Comment: `$this->price`: знак доллара не нужен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно так, пример выполнения http://ideone.com/0BswFM#stdin
Вы после `->` доллар поставили, это неправильно. Правильно `$this->title` и `$this->price`.

```
<?php

class ShopProduct{
  public $title = "prod";
  private $price = 0;

  function __construct($title, $price){
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->price = $price;
  }

  public function getPrice(){
    return $this->price;
  }
}

class Saller{
  function sale(ShopProduct $product, $sale){
    return $product->getPrice() + $sale;
  }
}

$product = new ShopProduct("dd", 50);
$saller  = new Saller();

echo $saller->sale($product, 0.1);
echo "<br />".$saller->sale($product, 0);
```

Comment: Добавьте комментарии. Так же ничего не понятно.

Comment: Вы не мне объясняйте, а ТС в ответе

Comment: возможно, стоило написать что с долларом все-таки можно (с примером), просто не в том виде как это автор делал

Comment: @BOPOH я не знаю где можно)) Вы можете дополнить ответ.

Comment: можно так: `$param = 'price'; $this->$param = 100`, т.е. доллар используется и будет все нормально работать, но надо знать когда это использовать ) Свои ответы я редко пишу, а чужие тем более не дополняю ))